# What type of engines are used on the RNLAF KDC-10 and KC-10's?

Tags: jet-engine, tanker, rnlaf

Does anyone know what type of engines are used on the Royal Netherlands Air Force's KC-10's/KDC-10's? I did some research and found out that they are GE CF6-50 engines, but what comes after the "50"? Is it a -50C2B, for example? Or a -50A?

Answer (score 5):

The Dutch defence department [website](https://www.defensie.nl/onderwerpen/materieel/vliegtuigen-en-helikopters/mcdonnell-douglas-kdc-10) has the answer:

> motoren: 3 maal CF6-50C2 turbofan

Which translates to

> engines: 3 times CF6-50C2 turbofan